# some http packets not reaching host

Tags: networking, http

we are experiencing a very strange issue with http traffic between 2 machines on the same network: when sending an HTTP request there are some packets not reaching the other host as you can see from the tcpdump. Does anybody have an idea as to what could cause such a problem and what tests can we do to troubleshoot it?

Thank you in advance.

server A (x.x.x.67):

```
10:52:54.766961 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [S], seq 3933450573, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1799470837 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:54.767169 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [S.], seq 2443943736, ack 3933450574, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2928651146 ecr 1799470837,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:54.767185 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799470838 ecr 2928651146], length 0
10:52:54.767310 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799470838 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:52:54.967964 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799471039 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:52:55.168969 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799471240 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:52:55.571973 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799471643 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:52:55.948432 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [S.], seq 2443943736, ack 3933450574, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2928652328 ecr 1799470837,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:55.948455 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799472019 ecr 2928651146], length 0
10:52:56.376977 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799472448 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:52:57.948432 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [S.], seq 2443943736, ack 3933450574, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2928654328 ecr 1799470837,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:57.948451 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799474019 ecr 2928651146], length 0
10:52:57.988966 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799474060 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:52:59.780422 ARP, Request who-has x.x.x.67 tell x.x.x.51, length 46
10:52:59.780437 ARP, Reply x.x.x.67 is-at x:x:x:x:x:1f, length 28
10:53:01.208971 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799477280 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:53:01.948448 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [S.], seq 2443943736, ack 3933450574, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2928658328 ecr 1799470837,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:53:01.948459 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799478019 ecr 2928651146], length 0
10:53:07.657010 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483728 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:53:07.657235 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [.], ack 242, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928664036 ecr 1799483728], length 0
10:53:07.785710 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [.], seq 1:1449, ack 242, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928664165 ecr 1799483728], length 1448
10:53:07.785722 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 1449, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483856 ecr 2928664165], length 0
10:53:07.785884 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [P.], seq 1449:2105, ack 242, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928664165 ecr 1799483856], length 656
10:53:07.785891 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 2105, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483856 ecr 2928664165], length 0
10:53:07.785977 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [F.], seq 242, ack 2105, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483857 ecr 2928664165], length 0
10:53:07.791437 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [F.], seq 2105, ack 243, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928664171 ecr 1799483857], length 0
10:53:07.791447 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 2106, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483862 ecr 2928664171], length 0
```

server B (x.x.x.51):

```
10:52:54.769644 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [S], seq 3933450573, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1799470837 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:54.769666 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [S.], seq 2443943736, ack 3933450574, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2928651146 ecr 1799470837,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:55.950929 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [S.], seq 2443943736, ack 3933450574, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2928652328 ecr 1799470837,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:57.950927 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [S.], seq 2443943736, ack 3933450574, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2928654328 ecr 1799470837,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:59.782918 ARP, Request who-has x.x.x.67 tell x.x.x.51, length 28
10:52:59.783093 ARP, Reply x.x.x.67 is-at x:x:x:x:x:1f, length 46
10:53:01.950939 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [S.], seq 2443943736, ack 3933450574, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2928658328 ecr 1799470837,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:53:07.659702 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:242, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483728 ecr 2928651146], length 241
10:53:07.659726 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [.], ack 242, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928664036 ecr 1799483728], length 0
10:53:07.788181 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [.], seq 1:1449, ack 242, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928664165 ecr 1799483728], length 1448
10:53:07.788374 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 1449, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483856 ecr 2928664165], length 0
10:53:07.788381 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [P.], seq 1449:2105, ack 242, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928664165 ecr 1799483856], length 656
10:53:07.788536 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 2105, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483856 ecr 2928664165], length 0
10:53:07.788614 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [F.], seq 242, ack 2105, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483857 ecr 2928664165], length 0
10:53:07.793955 IP x.x.x.51.http > x.x.x.67.46526: Flags [F.], seq 2105, ack 243, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928664171 ecr 1799483857], length 0
10:53:07.794094 IP x.x.x.67.46526 > x.x.x.51.http: Flags [.], ack 2106, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1799483862 ecr 2928664171], length 0
```

Comment: What about `ifconfig` error counters?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a MTU-related problem.

To test, try lowering your MTU on both servers issuing the command `ifconfig <ifname> mtu 580`

This should be only viewed as a workaround, though. If that solves the problem, restore the original MTU (issuing `ifconfig <ifname> mtu 1500` and check with your firewall admin / ISP why larger packet are dropped.

Comment: hi, thank you for the input. I tried to lower the mtu on both machines and run the request again but the problem still remains.